# Zoom in on h1 depending on what radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a radio button is selected/checked, the h1 throughout the webpage needs to zoom in or out depending on the radio option the user selects/checks, I have the following code:

```html
<form id="title_size_options" action="">
  
 <input type="radio" onClick="document.getElementsByTagName('h1').style.zoom = '80%';" id="font_size_h1_small" name="title_size_option_choice" value="title_size_option_one">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  
 <input type="radio" onClick="document.getElementsByTagName('h1').style.zoom = '100%';"  name="title_size_option_choice" value="title_size_option_two" Checked="yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  
 <input type="radio" onClick="document.getElementsByTagName('h1').style.zoom = '130%';"  name="title_size_option_choice" value="title_size_option_three">


</form>
```

I don't want to resize the text using .style.fontSize = "50px" - or something like that JS code - because the h1 elements are different sizes throughout the page.

Thanks - any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var currentZoom = 1.0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_ZoomIn').click(
            function () {
                $('#divName').animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom += .1 }, 'slow');
            })

    });
```

Comment: exactly what i needed - I just replaced the '#divName' with 'h1' and whenever the user chose to select the option to zoom out I replaced the '+=' with '-='